# Subscriptions - Recurring payments (Fiat to Crypto wallet)

Tags: transfer, payments, scheduling

I checked several platforms (BitPay, Stripe, Plaid etc..) but none seem to enable me to setup a recurring payment from fiat to a crypto wallet the same way you would do it on Netflix with your bank card.
I need to put this in place to, then, be able to trigger a wallet to SC transfer in my app. That will ease non crypto-native user onboarding as the flow will literally look like what they already know: **can anyone recommend a solution/platform for this?**

PS: most of the fiat on-ramp services would offer direct buy but within their own ecosystem, like USD (user bank) -> USDT (user Binance wallet) on Binance...which is not covering my use case + add unexpected hurdles like KYC etc... whereas I am just moving $10

Comment: damn so I guess it doesn't exist yet then..

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: hi, yes we are using Stripe + Circle for fiat and Diagonal for direct crypto ;)

Comment: ok, so from the pov of the user, it seems like 1 transaction right? As the rest is all taken part of behind scenes?

Comment: yes this is correct

Comment: Great! What's the product called, I'd love to check it out